# Search "AND", "OR", "NOT" in the text of a document using OracleText

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

OracleText has special meaning for these words. What if the text itself has them?

For example, d1.txt has "cats and dogs" and d2.txt has "cats". When searching for phrase "cats and dogs" i should get d1.txt only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up for literal words by surrounding them with curly braces:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(column, '{cats and dogs}') > 0
```

In the reference books those are in the sections:

- [Special characters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqspcl.htm#i1006181)
- [Query operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cqoper.htm#i996733)

Comment: Thanks. I have just tried that. Its working (no exception). The problem is, while its able to match exact phrase, it not work for "like" like queries, means would not match for "and" ({"and"}) in the above file.

Comment: @user653663: You can mix full expressions and Like queries: `CONTAINS(col, '{cats and dogs} AND rain%') > 0`

Comment: What if I want to find all documents that contains the word "and"? I have tried: [select Id from DocVersion where contains(RandomNameFile, 'and', 1) > 0;], no error, not found any records. I have also tried [select Id from DocVersion where contains(RandomNameFile, '{and}', 1) > 0;], no error, no result. This is working [select Id from DocVersion where contains(RandomNameFile, 'cats and dogs', 1) > 0;], no error, found records.

Comment: @user653663: That's because your lexer parameters have `AND` in the stopword list. So this word is not indexed at all. Modify the stop list (see the CONTEXT index parameters section of the documentation for that).

Comment: Thanks. Default behavior of returning nothing when searching for "and", "or", "not" etc and also "this", "that" etc is appropriate, so I am leaving it like that. About phrases that uses these reserved words but also have other words, for example: "cats and dogs", "not empty" etc I am encapsulating the entire search string  in braces, to make "{cats and dogs}", "{not empty}" etc as you suggested.